# Automation in R? Creating values from repeating values within multiple columns?

Tags: r, loops, automation, vectorization, apply

I have code right now that is incredibly tedious and I would like to condense it to make it more efficient and less prone to human error. Right now I have a dataset:

```
month <- rep(c(1:9), times = 10)
age <- rep(c(1:5), times = 18)
period <- rep(c(1:3))
value_1 <- rep(c(0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.7, 0.9), times = 9)
df <- data.frame(period, month, age, value_1)
```

My current code looks like this:

```
period1_age1_month1<- c(ifelse(df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==1 & df$age==1]- 1 <= 0, 0, df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==1 & df$age==1]- 1), df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==1 & df$age==1]+ 1)
period1_age1_month2<- c(ifelse(df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==2 & df$age==1]- 1 <= 0, 0, df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==2 & df$age==1]- 1), df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==2 & df$age==1]+ 1)
period1_age1_month3<- c(ifelse(df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==3 & df$age==1]- 1 <= 0, 0, df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==3 & df$age==1]- 1), df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==3 & df$age==1]+ 1)
period1_age1_month4<- c(ifelse(df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==4 & df$age==1]- 1 <= 0, 0, df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==4 & df$age==1]- 1), df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==4 & df$age==1]+ 1)
period1_age1_month5<- c(ifelse(df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==5 & df$age==1]- 1 <= 0, 0, df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==5 & df$age==1]- 1), df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==5 & df$age==1]+ 1)
period1_age1_month6<- c(ifelse(df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==6 & df$age==1]- 1 <= 0, 0, df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==6 & df$age==1]- 1), df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==6 & df$age==1]+ 1)
period1_age1_month7<- c(ifelse(df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==7 & df$age==1]- 1 <= 0, 0, df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==7 & df$age==1]- 1), df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==7 & df$age==1]+ 1)
period1_age1_month8<- c(ifelse(df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==8 & df$age==1]- 1 <= 0, 0, df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==8 & df$age==1]- 1), df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==8 & df$age==1]+ 1)
period1_age1_month9<- c(ifelse(df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==9 & df$age==1]- 1 <= 0, 0, df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==9 & df$age==1]- 1), df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==9 & df$age==1]+ 1)


period1_age2_month1<- c(ifelse(df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==1 & df$age==2]- 1 <= 0, 0, df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==1 & df$age==2]- 1), df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==1 & df$age==2]+ 1)
period1_age2_month2<- c(ifelse(df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==2 & df$age==2]- 1 <= 0, 0, df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==2 & df$age==2]- 1), df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==2 & df$age==2]+ 1)
period1_age2_month3<- c(ifelse(df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==3 & df$age==2]- 1 <= 0, 0, df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==3 & df$age==2]- 1), df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==3 & df$age==2]+ 1)
period1_age2_month4<- c(ifelse(df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==4 & df$age==2]- 1 <= 0, 0, df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==4 & df$age==2]- 1), df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==4 & df$age==2]+ 1)
period1_age2_month5<- c(ifelse(df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==5 & df$age==2]- 1 <= 0, 0, df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==5 & df$age==2]- 1), df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==5 & df$age==2]+ 1)
period1_age2_month6<- c(ifelse(df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==6 & df$age==2]- 1 <= 0, 0, df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==6 & df$age==2]- 1), df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==6 & df$age==2]+ 1)
period1_age2_month7<- c(ifelse(df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==7 & df$age==2]- 1 <= 0, 0, df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==7 & df$age==2]- 1), df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==7 & df$age==2]+ 1)
period1_age2_month8<- c(ifelse(df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==8 & df$age==2]- 1 <= 0, 0, df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==8 & df$age==2]- 1), df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==8 & df$age==2]+ 1)
period1_age2_month9<- c(ifelse(df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==9 & df$age==2]- 1 <= 0, 0, df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==9 & df$age==2]- 1), df$value_1[df$period==1 & df$month==9 & df$age==2]+ 1)
```

However, it goes on for each age group, and then once each age group is represented, it repeats for each period. Every week, I receive a new dataset for a new period, then I have to go back and add the new period (4, then 5, then 6), which makes the code incredibly long and also time consuming to update. The code is hundreds of lines long. I am at the point where it will be easier to sit with this code and automate it rather than copy and paste, but replacing each period/age.

I am very new to R and do not have any experience automating. I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction. Either a loop, vectorization, or apply seem like the way to go. However, I am at a loss on how to start. If anyone has any insight to this, I would really appreciate any help.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Read [ask] and [MCVE]

Comment: Also please share an example of your expected outcome, i.e. currently you store a lot of vectors. Would you rather like to have the results appended to your data as new columns?

Comment: The output right now is stored as many (hundreds of) vectors, but I would rather it not be like this. I think adding two new columns to the data frame makes more sense and is much easier to work with! Thank you so much for your response! I appreciate your help and patience.

Comment: I think it would be easier to understand your goal if you share your expected output for the `df` shared.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing what your ultimate goal with your results is, you are currently trying to create a separate calculation for each combination of period/month/age. However, this is completely overkill. Your combinations can be derived from the data, i.e. each row represents a certain combination of period/month/age. Since your calculations for every combination are the same, you can just write the ifelse command once.

Note: this currently just appends the calculations to your data set. If that is sufficient is completely unknown (due to lack of information from To on the expected outcome).

```
df <- data.frame(month   = rep(c(1:9), times = 10),
                 age     = rep(c(1:5), times = 18),
                 period  = rep(c(1:3)),
                 value_1 = rep(c(0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.7, 0.9), times = 9))

library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(recode_down = if_else(value_1 - 1 <= 0, 0, value_1 - 1),
         recode_up   = value_1 + 1)
```

Result from the first 5 rows:

```
   period month age value_1 recode_down recode_up
1       1     1   1     0.1           0       1.1
2       2     2   2     0.3           0       1.3
3       3     3   3     0.4           0       1.4
4       1     4   4     0.7           0       1.7
5       2     5   5     0.9           0       1.9
```